# Get User Home Folder in Haxe

Tags: environment-variables, cross-platform, haxe

I'm looking for a way to get the path to the user's home folder that will work on any sys target. The only way I can think of is to use the `HOME`/`UserProfile` environment variable, but I can't find a cross-target way to get environment variable values. Is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Sys.getEnv()`](https://api.haxe.org/Sys.html?#getEnv) to obtain the value of the environment variable, and [`Sys.systemName()`](https://api.haxe.org/Sys.html?#systemName) to check which OS you're running on:

```
var home = Sys.getEnv(if (Sys.systemName() == "Windows") "UserProfile" else "HOME");
```

Comment: Just curious: what would `Sys.systemName` return on Android or iOS?

Comment: Depends on the target. If you're talking about hxcpp, it does have "Android", but I'm not sure what it uses on iOS. https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/6935